# python fabric error 'module' object has no attribute 'HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC'

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6, fabric

I am getting following error when I run fabric

```
(ENV)[root@server-124 ENV]# fab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fab", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Fabric==1.8.3', 'console_scripts', 'fab')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 299, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2229, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1948, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from fabric import api, state, colors
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from fabric.context_managers import (cd, hide, settings, show, path, prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/context_managers.py", line 42, in <module>
    from fabric.state import output, win32, connections, env
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/state.py", line 9, in <module>
    from fabric.network import HostConnectionCache, ssh
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 24, in <module>
    import paramiko as ssh
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 33, in <module>
    from paramiko import util
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/util.py", line 33, in <module>
    from paramiko.common import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/common.py", line 98, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import _UserFriendlyRNG
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 38, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random.Fortuna import FortunaAccumulator
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py", line 39, in <module>
    import FortunaGenerator
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py", line 34, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util.number import ceil_shift, exact_log2, exact_div
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py", line 56, in <module>
    if _fastmath is not None and not _fastmath.HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC'
```

I have referred some other post that says it "so you'reusing a newer version of PyCrypto with an older version of _fastmath." So I also installed gmp-devel

I am using virtualenv , Centos 6, Python 2.6

please help.

Comment: What version of GMP are you using? That function is only available in GMP 5.0 and later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

```
pip install PyCrypto==2.3
```

I didn't uninstall `python-crypto` because other packages I needed depended on it. I just ran the pip command above and everything worked :)